# wilcox.test get all the info test

Tags: r

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
  presence Var3 Var1 Var2
                              N     7.9  12.3  10.7
                              N     6.3  10.6  11.1
                              N     9.5  13.1  13.8
                              Y    33.2  13.4  12.9
                              Y     6.3  11.6  11.1
                              Y    14.5  13.8  12.9
                           ')
```

I run a wilcox.test for multiple column of a dataframe

```
 test_pw<- lapply(2:4, function(x) pairwise.wilcox.test(df[[x]], df$presence, mu=0))
```

I can only see the pvalue, however I would like to get more info regarding the test such as V (W)

```
    Pairwise comparisons using Wilcoxon rank sum test 

data:  df[[x]] and df$presence 

  H   
N 0.31

P value adjustment method: holm
```

something like that

```
Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  df$Var1 by df$presence
V = 21, p-value = 0.03125
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

when I run

```
lapply(test_pw, summary)
```

I get for each variable this:

```
[[3]]
                Length Class  Mode     
method          1      -none- character
data.name       1      -none- character
p.value         1      -none- numeric  
p.adjust.method 1      -none- character
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can run the code. Seems like all your values are probably in that list. Maybe `lapply(test_pw, summary)` is what you are after? It's not clear to me what the desired output is.

Comment: summary does not work

Comment: What does "does not work" mean exactly?

Comment: `pairwise.wilcox.test` doesnt return these. However, it call `wilcox.text` within it, and this does, so should be easy enough to write another that tweaks the function to return what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simply adding `summary()` inside your function should work.

```
test_pw<- lapply(3:5, function(x) summary(pairwise.wilcox.test(df[[x]], df$presence, mu=0)))
```

Comment: Putting summary inside the function, or `lapply`-ing it afterwards should make no difference.